# How to access a property in an itemController via the needs API in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

How can I access the properties of an itemController when I'm accessing the content of a controller via the needs API?

```
App.PostsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'post'
  someAction: -> console.log("i'm melting!")

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  someComputedProperty: (-> true ).property()

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend
  needs: ['postsIndex']
```

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#each post in controllers.postsIndex.content}}
    {{someComputedProperty}}
    <a {{action someAction target="postsIndex"}}>click</a>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

I tried `{{controllers.postsIndex.someComputedProperty}}` and `{{someComputedProperty}}` in the `index` template.

Comment: have you tried `{{#each post in controller itemController="post"}} {{someComputedProperty}} {{/each}}`?

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that someComputedProperty doesn't update when it changes, although it calculates correctly on page load. Also, adding `itemController` inline breaks the `someAction` (updated question with that part)

Comment: shouldn't the target be `controller`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I access the properties of an itemController when I'm accessing the content of a controller via the needs API?

First you should pass the `controllers.postsIndex` to the `{{each}}` helper instead of `controllers.postsIndex.content`. Otherwise the `{{each}}` helper will be looping over your model objects without going thru the `PostsIndexController`. So like @MilkyWayJoe suggested, try something like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#each post in controllers.postsIndex}}
    {{someComputedProperty}}
    <a {{action someAction target="postsIndex"}}>click</a>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

> I tried that, but it seems that someComputedProperty doesn't update when it changes, although it calculates correctly on page load.

Ember computed properties don't update unless you specify a list of dependencies:

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  someComputedProperty: (-> true ).property('title', 'someotherproperty', 'etc')
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, as the first half was right. Looping around the content was my problem. Setting the target of the action also worked. The part I was confused about was how `{{someComputedProperty}}` would know to access the itemController, but adding the `post` to the needs array in `IndexController` was the last piece. Thanks!